# AJAX syntax: Is this the way to do it?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to use AJAX to check if a user already exists in my database. For simplicity's sake I'll just check firstname and lastname for now. Here is what I got:

The .php file with the form and the JavaScript error handling:

```
$.get('verify_unique.php',{firstname:frm.add_fd2.value, lastname:frm.add_fd3.value},function(data){
  if (data.matches>0){
    var num_rows='1';
  }else{
    var num_rows='0';
  }
}, "json");


function check(frm) {
    var szAlert = "Invalid\n";
    var nIndex = 0;
     if (num_rows > 0) {
        nIndex++;
        szAlert += "- " +"This name already exists "+num_rows +" times\n";
     }
     if (!RequiredField(frm.add_fd1.value)) {
        nIndex++;
        szAlert += "- " +"'Title' cannot be blank\n";
     }
```

etc

The file verify_unique.php:

```
// DATABSE PARAMETERS
$link = @mysql_connect($host,$user,$passwd);
$database=mysql_select_db($db);
$firstname=$_GET['firstname'];
$lastname=$_GET['lastname'];
$result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM organisations WHERE FirstName="'.$firstname.'" AND LastName="'.$lastname.'"', $link);
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo '{matches:'.mysql_num_rows($result).'}';
?>
```

When I submit the form, not only doesnt it return my AJAX warning, it also skips my javascript checks. Unfortunately it doesn't throw any errors.
Can someone see where I went wrong?

Thanks
Marius

EDIT:
CURRENT SITUATION:

`$.get('verify_unique.php',{firstname:frm.add_fd2.value, lastname:frm.add_fd3.value},function(data){
      if (data.matches>0){
        var num_rows='1';
      }else{
        var num_rows='0';
      }
    }, "json");`

Debugger: frm is not defined.
frm is the name of the only form on this page, which can be called by javascript to perform sanity checks no problem.
Nothing changed in the verify_unique.php file

Comment: You can use Firebug or other debugger for checking what your javascript sends and php script returns.

Comment: You have not written any code to call your `check` function, which won't work even if it is called, since `num_rows` you try to use is local to the anonymous callback function of your AJAX request (it doesn't exist in the `check` function's scope).

Comment: Alexander: $ is not defined
[Break On This Error] $.get('verify_unique.php',{firstname:f...me:frm.add_fd3.value},function(data){

Comment: Dan: My javascript and AJAX skills are less than limited, can you simplify this for me?

Comment: `$` is not defined means you have not loaded the jQuery library before your code, while what you've written is not vanilla JavaScript, it's jQuery function calls.

Comment: DANGER: $result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM organisations WHERE FirstName="'.$firstname.'" AND LastName="'.$lastname.'"', $link);

Comment: Dan: Added /library/jQuery.php to my require section. Still the same error about $ not being defined.

Comment: @Marius: jQuery.php !?? jQuery is a javascript library... http://jquery.com/ add this to your `<head>` section: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` ... to be clear, I mean to your HTML! Not your PHP script.

Comment: Hi Dan, googled for the library and thats what google came up with ;) Added your line, debugger now says: frm is not defined - Do I have to escape this somehow?

Comment: @Mark , @Dan Grossman: Can't find a solution for this on google, tried a couple of suggestions but they come up with weird errors. Any ideas for that last bit?

Comment: OK had to put it inside the javascript, not as a 'script of its own'. Now I only need to figure out why the return value is not passed on, but thats tomorrows work ;)

Answer (score 1):

DANGER:

```
$result=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM organisations WHERE FirstName="'.$firstname.'" AND LastName="'.$lastname.'"', $link);
```

This is an invitation to SQL Injection attacks! You need to escape the firstnames and lastnames before you send them in to SQL.

Comment: Hi Zach, this is just for testing. First I want to make things work, then secure them up ;) Thanks for the reminder though.

Comment: @Marius - better to make the effort in the first instance, because once it "works", it's always too easy to just run with what you've got and forget that you still have work to do. (the number of bits of "prototype" software that end up in production is scary!)

Comment: Fair enough. But if I don't get it to work I'll just scratch this part and then I'll bite my ass about the additional work I put into it... Well escaping some variables isn't actually work but you know what I mean ;)